# Event for the BlackBerry menu key from within an LWUIT application?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I have made a non-touch application with [LWUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LWUIT). on J2ME devices all command menus work just fine. On a BlackBerry however this is not the case. At the moment, 'q' activates the left menu, and 'p' activates the right menu. I think this is automatic behavior because i didn't code anyhting for this to work.

I want to use the Blackberry-menu button to get the menu. How can I code this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi take a look at [Their blog post](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/11/building-project-on-blackberry.html) in theory it shows you how to do it [according to this post](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/blackberry-menu-button-0#comment-789167).

Comment: It looks very promising, but now I get an Error starting myApp: "Module 'Tapp-12' has verification error 2733 at offset 1858

Comment: no, I tried the lwuit blogspot and it now crashes at startup, so I don't know if it is solved. I hope when I remove the error, it will indeed be solved.